# Unvisible Sending of NAGA coins from Myetherwallet

Tags: myetherwallet

It's the first time for me to send tokens out of myetherwallet.
Yesterday I send some NAGA coins from myetherwallet to the exchange HitBTC platform. Everything is going fine with creating transaction and the NGC should be on pending but they're not. I can't see them on the pending transactions and the coins are somehow still in my token wallet. As I tried to send them again, it says that I do not have enough NGC token to send.
So are they on the way? Why can't I see the transaction?
Regards
Kessy

Comment: Hi there. Was a transaction hash generated to first time you tried to send them? What is the address you're sending them from?

Comment: Hi Richard. The sending adress/my address is: 0xA468c4Da12928dBCCB6DE84F07753ba4076ACeEB

Comment: No, i tryed ti send them few times, but because of the fees, it didn't work. Later it works and it went as transaction complete or something like that.

Comment: I have problems too, cant see my NAGA coins (14) and there no transaction record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you do not have enough ether to pay for the transaction gas.

The last few transfers show

- 37458 gas at 23 Gwei gives 0.000861534 Ether ($1.01)
- 37458 gas at 40 Gwei gives 0.00149832 Ether ($1.76)
- 37458 gas at 20 Gwei gives 0.00074916 Ether ($0.88)

And the balance in your address is  0.00014995 Ether ($0.18)

Comment: Hi Ismael, yes, now I dont have enough ETH to send it but before I sent to ETH out, I had enough to pay the gas so I made the transaction. It's so confusing. What's the best thing I can do to get this NGC out of this wallet?

Comment: To move the NGC tokens you need to pay for the gas, if you do not have enough ether you will not be able to move the tokens. Transfer some ether and move your tokens, then move the remaining ether to some other account.

Comment: Thx Ismael, case solved. I sent them again with maximal gas :)